# deny inheritance only from parent folder?

Tags: c#, ntfs

I have 4 folders in my application with certain permissions on each...

folder1 has folder2 inside it, folder2 has folder3 and folder4 in it

im able to deny inheritance from folder2 to folder3 with the below code, but i want to have inheritance from folder1 to folder 3?

i want the folder to inherit all the properties from folder1

```
        string folderpath="xyz";
        string UserAccount = "asp";
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo FolderInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderpath);
        DirectorySecurity FolderAcl = new DirectorySecurity();
        FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount,       FileSystemRights.ReadData, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
        const bool protectRulesFromInheritance = true;
        const bool preserveInheritance = true;
        FolderAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection(protectRulesFromInheritance, preserveInheritance);
        FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only inherit from your parent.  Inheritance from a grandparent only happens implicitly; that is, if you inherit from your parent and your parent inherits from *its* parent, you will have implicit grandparent-inheritance.

If this *were* possible, the administration (both internally and in terms of user interface) would be horrendous, especially when it comes to moving folders around...

Comment: There's no way to automatically inherit filesystem permissions from anything other than the immediate parent.  You could implement something in your application, if you're manipulating the filesystem, but outside of the application the OS wouldn't respect or recognise it.